# Java Equivalent of C# Anonymous Arrays and Lists?

Tags: c#, java, arrays, collections

C# lets me make arrays on the fly when I need to pass them into functions. Let's say I have a method called `findMiddleItem(String[] items)`. In C#, I can write code like:

```
findMiddleItem(new String[] { "one", "two", "three" });
```

It's awesome, because it means I don't have to write:

```
IList<String> strings = new List<String>();
strings.add("one");
strings.add("two");
strings.add("three");
findMiddleItem(strings.ToArray());
```

Which sucks, because I don't really care about `strings` -- it's just a construct to let me pass a string array into a method that requires it. A method which I can't modify.

So how do you do this in Java? I need to know this for array types (eg. String[]) but also generic types (eg. List).

Comment: For reference, in C# you can simply do, new [] { "one", "two" }

Comment: so many incorrect answers :) - you need varags known as ...

Comment: @bestsss you probably mean *varargs*. Talking about incorrect...

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd: sure it's a typo

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A List and an Array are fundamentally different things.

A [`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is a [`Collection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) type, an implementation of an interface.
An Array is a special operating system specific data structure that can only be created through either a special syntax or native code.

### Arrays

In Java, the array syntax is identical to the one you are describing:

```
String[] array = new String[] { "one", "two", "three" };
```

**Reference:** [Java tutorial > Arrays](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

### Lists

The easiest way to create a List is this:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
```

However, the resulting list will be immutable (or at least it won't support `add()` or `remove()`), so you can wrap the call with an ArrayList constructor call:

```
new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three"));
```

As Jon Skeet says, it's prettier with Guava, there you can do:

```
Lists.newArrayList("one", "two", "three");
```

Reference: [`Java Tutorial > The List Interface`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html), [`Lists` (guava javadocs)](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html)

### VarArgs

About this comment:

> It would be nice if we would be able to do findMiddleItem({ "one", "two", "three" });

Java varargs gives you an even better deal:

```
public void findMiddleItem(String ... args){
    //
}
```

you can call this using a variable number of arguments:

```
findMiddleItem("one");
findMiddleItem("one", "two");
findMiddleItem("one", "two", "three");
```

Or with an array:

```
findMiddleItem(new String[]{"one", "two", "three"});
```

Reference: [`Java Tutorial > Arbitrary Number of Arguments`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs)

Comment: Thank you. You read between the lines and figured out that I want to create a List type in Java using C#-style array initialization. The secret sauce was Arrays.asList(new String[] { ... }), which is awesome.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it the exact same way:

```
findMiddleItem(new String[] { "one", "two", "three" });
```

is valid in Java. Assuming that `findMiddleItem` is defined as:

```
findMiddleItem(String[] array)
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java you can construct an array in the same way:

```
findMiddleItem(new String[] { "one", "two", "three" });
```

You can't construct a `List<T>` in quite the same way, but there are various ways of getting around that, e.g. wrapping an array, or using some of the [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) `Lists.*` methods. (Your code trying to call `findMiddleItem` with an argument of type `IList<string>` wouldn't have compiled, as an `IList<string>` isn't necessarily a `string[]`.) For example, if `findMiddleItem` actually had a parameter of type `List<String>` you could use:

```
findMiddleItem(Lists.newArrayList("one", "two", "three"));
```

As well as not having collection initializers (or object initializers), Java *also* doesn't have implicitly typed arrays... your original C# code can be condensed in C# 3 and higher:

```
findMiddleItem(new[] { "one", "two", "three" });
```

Comment: It would be nice if we would be able to do `findMiddleItem({ "one", "two", "three" });`

Comment: @fastcodejava: Of course if `findMiddleItem` had been declared using varargs you could just use `findMiddleItem("one", "two", "three")`.

Answer (score 2):

The same way as in C# `findMiddleItem(new String[] { "one", "two", "three" })`;

Also, for future reference, you can construct a List in Java in a slightly less-verbose way<sup>*</sup>:

```
List<String> myStringList = new ArrayList<String>() {{
   add("a");
   add("b");
   add("c");
}};
```

<sup>*</sup> As Sean pointed out, this can be considered bad practice since it does create an anonymous subclass of `ArrayList`.

Comment: I'd consider this bad practice. You are creating an anonymous subclass of ArrayList. There's no need to pollute your code base with unneeded classes.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the exact same syntax in Java.  This works:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        method1( new String[] {"this", "is", "a", "test"} );
    }


    private static void method1( String[] params )
    {
        for( String string : params )
            System.out.println( string );
    }
}
```

I think this will work on non-static methods, too.

Comment: And here I thought I had the first answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using vargs like

```
findMiddleItem("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
```

you can do

```
findMiddleItem("one,two,three,four,five".split(","));
```

EDIT: to turn a String into a List you can use a helper method.

```
public static List<String> list(String text) {
    return Arrays.asList(text.split(","));
}

findMiddleItem(list("one,two,three,four,five"));
```

Comment: Won't work with a list, though. Unless you use Arrays.asList("...".split(...)).